# Rails will not follow Devise timeoutable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm showing the related codes of Devise timeoutable

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable, :timeoutable
   .....
end
```

and `/config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.timeout_in = 1.day
```

It was worked perfectly, recently I have implemented [`Rails Action Cable`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) for some background jobs as like `/app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb`

```
module ApplicationCable
    class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
        identified_by :current_user

        def connect 
            self.current_user = find_verified_user
            logger.add_tags "ActionCable", current_user.email
        end

        private

        def find_verified_user
            current_user = env['warden'].user
            if current_user
                current_user
            else
                reject_unauthorized_connection
            end
        end
    end
end
```

the unsubscribe method

```
def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
    $redis.del "user_#{ current_user.id }_online"
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'online_indicator', userId: current_user.id, online: false
end
```

and after implemented this Rails automatically destroyed the session after sometimes inactive the user I mean logged out.

I don't know what is happening with this code.

Could anyone figure out what is this, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have any `disconnect` method or is anything cleaning :current_user when channel is closed? I think the problem is channel being closed and that cleaning current_user

Comment: Yes I have `unsubscribe` method, please check the below of the question where I added the method

Comment: As I read from the redis gem you may be (not sure, but try it) deleting user session if you are using redis to store user session. I would try without cleaning redis, just disconnecting user from channel. Let me know if this change anything

Comment: I'm in the process, so let me check, Thanks

Comment: Could you please here what exactly mean by `deleting user session`, I'm commented out this line `$redis.del "user_#{ current_user.id }_online"` in unsubscribe method but not effected anything, everything is usual. Thanks

Comment: I was meaning to clean `env['warden'].user` (the var you are using to authenticate in the connect). But if you are commenting redis line and the problem persist it should be something else. I would try just to make sure the problem is not active-admin to delete the unsuscribe method and let me know